# Showing a function is zero function

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Prove or disprove the following statement:
If $f\in C^{\infty}$ and $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all integers $k\geq0$ then $f=0$. Here $C^{\infty}$ is the set of all functions which are infinitely many times differentiable

I think the statement is true. If we write the Taylor Series of $f$ at 0 we get
$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n$ but by hypothesis $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ . Hence $f=0$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yep.  Correct...

Comment: Your proof is not complete. You would need to show that the Taylor series converges to the function. As shown below, however, the statement is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the counter example: Let
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
e^{(-1/x^2)} & \text{if $x \neq 0$}\\
0 & \text{if $x = 0$}
\end{cases} 
 $$

The point is that among the real functions there is a function that is infinitely differentiable but does not coincide its Taylor series.

Comment: So are there only some special functions which coincides with its Taylor Series?

Comment: @Shreya Chauhan yep and they are called analytic functions. however you can still approximate your function by degree k Taylor polynomial with known bound when your function is k times differentiable

Answer (score 2):

The statement is incorrect.

Here is a well known counterexample:

\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases} 
      0 & x\leq 0 \\
      e^{-\frac{1}{x}} & x>0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Functions with such property helps construct nontrivial elements in $\mathcal{C}^\infty(\Omega):=\{f\in\mathcal{C}^\infty|support(f)\subset\Omega\}$, where $\Omega$ is compact. See any textbook for the theory of distribution. Here is [one](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Estein/lehre/SoSem09/distrvo.pdf).